# Where to save SQL Table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I created SQL Azure Database and made connection with database using SSMS. When I create a table I have to save it somewhere and no matter where I save it I can't see a table in Object Explorer and cannot link to it with Query. Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you creating a table? Through SSMS table Designer or by running `Create Table ...` query?

Comment: With T-SQL @Sac (query)

Comment: Have you get any error while executing query? It should be shown under Tables in Object Explorer.. Have you try restarting SSMS?

Comment: I tried everything but nothing works.. Yes, when I try to run query it says Invalid object name [table name] .. @Sac

Comment: What do you mean "save a table"? Either you created the table with `CREATE` or you didn't. Please post the statement you used to create the table. Did an error occur when you executed your CREATE statement? Were you using a transaction that you rolled back? Are you connecting to the correct database?

Comment: Thank You @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't run query, just try to save databse(Ctrl + S) like I would do that in design mode ...

Comment: From the last comment, it sounds like you may not be executing the `CREATE` statement. Please click on the “! Execute” button (or press F5) to execute the query and let us know if you get any errors. Thanks

Comment: Everything is fine @Raul G ..

Comment: @arma_best: you should probably reply to your post with the answer that solved your problem, and close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my problem, I never runed query just tried to save table on my laptop..